# How to disable or remove persistent cart in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am currently using 3.5.7 version of WC. But I cannot find a way to disable the persistent cart feature of Woocommerce.

Can anyone give me a solution for my issue?

Comment: [How can we improve WooCommerce? Persistent cart](http://ideas.woocommerce.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/6331814-persistent-cart)

Comment: The answer posted are not working in the new version of wc.

Comment: The filter that has been created specifically on Woocommerce 3.4 does work. Anyways you need to search first and to give in your question the code attempts that you have tried, with some context and explanations. I kindly remember you that stackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_updated', 'delete_persistent_cart' );
function delete_persistent_cart() {
    if ( get_current_user_id() ) {
        $wc = WooCommerce::instance();
        $wc->cart->persistent_cart_destroy();
    }
}
```

This goes into your child themes `function.php` file and disables the persistent cart.

Comment: I already tried that but it does not at work. after i put that code in my function-child.php, i cleared my browser cache but the issue still there.

Comment: Have you select your child theme as theme?

Comment: I double check it and it yes. child is my theme.

Comment: @SuriLane Okay so we'll try another way. Please check it on your page and let me know if it does what you want.

Comment: My site does not load after i put that code. It says "This page isn't working"

Comment: @SuriLane I've forgot the closing tag. Updated the code.

Comment: I put a closing }. but still the persistent cart still there.

Comment: @SuriLane Have you updated the cart? Because we're using the update cart hook. This get's normally triggered when someone add something to the cart or updates them. I think your cart is already there so you need to trigger it again.

Comment: Yes. I added some items then close the browser. after that i tried to access my page, the session end but the cart items remains.